# UNION on 2 joined queries

Tags: sql, db2, union

I have 2 working queries that are joined by subselects using `WITH` in DB2.

They each work separately but I can't seem to find the best way to properly combine or union them.

The first query:

```
  with c as(
select
  employee,
  sum(salesPrice) as priorSpecifics
from schema1.orders g
    inner join dateSchema.dates d
    on g.dateField = d.dateField
where  d.newDate between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31'
and g.details = 'CategoryOne'
group by employee
), d as(
select
  employee,
  sum(salesPrice) as priorTotals
from schema1.orders g
    inner join dateSchema.dates d
    on g.dateField = d.dateField
where  d.newDate between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31'
group by employee
)
Select  ifnull(c.employee,d.employee) as employee
      ,c.priorSpecifics
      ,d.priorTotals
      ,cast(Round((DEC(c.priorSpecifics,12,2)/DEC(d.priorTotals,12,2)) * 100,2) as decimal(12,2)) as priorPercent
  from c full join d ON (c.employee = d.employee);
```

Returns 4 columns

and the 2nd query

```
with c as(
select
  employee,
  sum(salesPrice) as currentSpecifics
from schema1.orders g
    inner join dateSchema.dates d
    on g.dateField = d.dateField
where  d.newDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31'
and g.details = 'CategoryOne'
group by employee
), d as(
select
  employee,
  sum(salesPrice) as currentTotals
from schema1.orders g
    inner join dateSchema.dates d
    on g.dateField = d.dateField
where  d.newDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31'
group by employee
)
Select  ifnull(c.employee,d.employee) as employee
      ,c.currentSpecifics
      ,d.currentTotals
      ,cast(Round((DEC(c.currentSpecifics,12,2)/DEC(d.currentTotals,12,2)) * 100,2) as decimal(12,2)) as currentPercent
  from c full join d ON (c.employee = d.employee);
```

Returns 4 as well. The field `employee` is the only thing that is shared between all.

How can I combine this into one query to get one employee column and then all of my sum/percent columns following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do everything you want with conditional aggregation:

```
select employee,
       sum(case when d.newDate between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31' and g.details = 'CategoryOne' then salesPrice end) as priorSpecifics,
       sum(case when d.newDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' and g.details = 'CategoryOne' then salesPrice end) as currentSpecifics,
       sum(case when d.newDate between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31' then salesPrice end) as priorTotals,
       sum(case when d.newDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' then salesPrice end) as currentTotals
from schema1.orders g inner join
     dateSchema.dates d
     on g.dateField = d.dateField
group by employee;
```

I'll let you fill in with the additional calculations.

Comment: Trying to use the aliases here for percentages won't work, though if I stick the whole calculation into each end of the division then it works. Is there no way in DB2 to use aliases in the select as conditions for other select columns?

Answer (score 1):

If all the above queries are working then you already have everything you need.  
You must combine from the 1st group, the first 2 to make the `prior` query, then 
from the 2nd group to make the `cur` query 
 
and finally join the `prior` query to the `cur` query:

```
with 
c as(
select
  employee,
  sum(salesPrice) as priorSpecifics
from schema1.orders g
    inner join dateSchema.dates d
    on g.dateField = d.dateField
where  d.newDate between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31'
and g.details = 'CategoryOne'
group by employee
),

d as(
select
  employee,
  sum(salesPrice) as priorTotals
from schema1.orders g
    inner join dateSchema.dates d
    on g.dateField = d.dateField
where  d.newDate between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31'
group by employee
),

prior as (
Select  ifnull(c.employee,d.employee) as employee
      ,c.priorSpecifics
      ,d.priorTotals
      ,cast(Round((DEC(c.priorSpecifics,12,2)/DEC(d.priorTotals,12,2)) * 100,2) as decimal(12,2)) as priorPercent
  from c full join d ON (c.employee = d.employee)
),

e as(
select
  employee,
  sum(salesPrice) as currentSpecifics
from schema1.orders g
    inner join dateSchema.dates d
    on g.dateField = d.dateField
where  d.newDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31'
and g.details = 'CategoryOne'
group by employee
),

f as(
select
  employee,
  sum(salesPrice) as currentTotals
from schema1.orders g
    inner join dateSchema.dates d
    on g.dateField = d.dateField
where  d.newDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31'
group by employee
),

cur as (
Select  ifnull(e.employee,f.employee) as employee
      ,e.currentSpecifics
      ,f.currentTotals
      ,cast(Round((DEC(e.currentSpecifics,12,2)/DEC(f.currentTotals,12,2)) * 100,2) as decimal(12,2)) as currentPercent
  from e full join f ON (e.employee = f.employee)
)

Select  ifnull(p.employee, c.employee) as employee
      ,p.priorSpecifics
      ,p.priorTotals
      ,p.priorPercent
      ,c.currentSpecifics
      ,c.currentTotals
      ,c.currentPercent
from prior p full join cur c ON (c.employee = c.employee);
```